# ListView with checkboxes or multiple listeners for list item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listeners

I realise that this question has been asked a lot and i've read the first 2 pages of google about it but i couldn't find an answer that worked. 
Basically i want a ListView with custom items, each one should have a checkbox. How can i make it so that when i click a checkbox the equivalent of listView.setItemChecked(int, boolean)... would happen? 
Some of the answers i've found required having another boolean in the list objects, or some would reuse the checkboxes so they reappear checked further down the list. Is there a way to have a checkbox modify something in the listView or how could i add multiple listeners to a list item? For example when i clicked the text something would happen but clicking the image would trigger something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for multiple items at a list row easily. just listen for them inside your list adapter getView method after finding them.

hope it helps